# In Microsoft Word, my style is affecting other paragraphs around the word I'm trying to change

Tags: microsoft-word

In my Word document, I'm trying to position one word in the center between two paragraphs in the middle of my chapter. The body text, and the symbol I'm moving, all have the same style affected.

I've been able to move this symbol in other places to the center without issue. But in some cases, the symbol and the paragraph above or below it gets moved as well after I assign a different style to that symbol.

I've tried modifying several styles, including Normal, and have found 'Update' to be unchecked in every instance.

What could be making this happen and how do I change it so I can move the symbol to the center without affecting paragraphs around it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your issue isn't really clear.  Can you be more specific?  Maybe post a screenshot?

Comment: Do you have 'show hidden text' on so that you can see the paragraph marks?  Are you dragging the paragraph mark in some cases when you move the symbol?  Does the symbol always have it's own paragraph mark (separate from the paragraphs above and below it)?